# UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput in iOS7

Tags: ios, authentication, uialertview, landscape, ios7

I'm testing my working application on iOS7. When the application starts it asks to the player to login. To gather user credentials I'm using the AlertView with style **UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput**

It looks fine in iOS6

[image]

but something strange is happening on iOS7

[image]

The AlertView UILabel which contains the title is still there but it is hidden because seems to have an overstimated height. Scrolling the UILabel eventually show the title.

Answer (score 0):

As I have experimented with my work while I was porting my application to iOS 7 that there are some variations in the pixel. The app had to be reconfigured for the same. I would suggest to adjust the height of the dialog boxes manually to fit the screen.

P.S.: I am still learning phase so avoid if I am not correct in what I say and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi killswitch. I'd rather not change the height of native views. I'll give a try but I think there should be another way to accomplish this.

Comment: Not a good idea... trying to change the height. You can make it taller, but Apple frowns on subclassing UIAlertView. The only thing you could do... create your own. I saw one here on stackoverflow, with a controller someone had created to do that. Me... I don't need it or want to mess with it. Sooner or later... it might break. Code rot is a terrible thing! An example: addSubview in the AlertView. Causing a lot of people headaches, me included... until I used the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to make the Title or Message a special height. Eliminate the height change and allow the system to create the heigh automatically.

You didn't post any code, so, I'm just guessing.

I just swapped my alert view code out for iOS7, which is much simpler than the old style.
_prompt here is a property set up as an UIAlertView

```
- (IBAction) addEntryTapped:(id)sender
{
    [_editorTextView resignFirstResponder];
    [self saveTextChanges];
    [self dismissPopovers];
    _prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    // change the UIAlertViewStyle to the one you need to use
    _prompt.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField *text = [_prompt textFieldAtIndex:0];
    _textField = text;
    [_prompt setDelegate:self];
    [_prompt setTitle:@"New Entry Title..."];
    [_prompt setMessage:@""];
    [_prompt addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [_prompt addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    [_textField setPlaceholder:@"New Entry Title"];
    _textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    _textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    [_prompt show];

    // set cursor and show keyboard
    [_textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

[image: The alert with the change John requested.]

Comment: Hi Marc. Please try to change the UIAlterView style from UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput to UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput and let me know what you see. Use a landscape layout for your view!

Comment: I already use this same format for my login, with the change you asked for. But, I did it to the very code above and it comes out as it should.

Comment: Is the view in landscape mode? Did the keyboard appear when the dialog appear or it is initially hidden? Sorry for querying you a lot but i need to understand why my dialog is "malformed" ;D

Comment: My app is for iPad... of course it has no issues regardless of orientation. Just had a thought... are you viewing the screen in iPhone or iPhone Retina? When you choose which version, choose the retina version of the simulator.